# Malformed JSON when reading from File

Tags: php, json

I will start off by saying that I am pretty new to using php and JSON, so if I have made any dumb mistakes, please be kind. :)

I am working on trying to read a JSON file that is saved on my server. When I try to do a json_decode(), it returns null. I believe that this has to do with line feeds or formatting of the file when it was created, because if I do something like:
`$json_string = '{"tomorrow":"2018-09-15"}';`
then the decode works properly. Am I doing something wrong in the making of the JSON file, or is there something extra I need to do with the file to make it compatible with the decode? Been working on this for a couple of days now, and it's driving me crazy. Any guidance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my php code:

```php
$filePath = 'test.json';
    $json_string = file_get_contents($filePath);
    //$json_string = '{"tomorrow":"2018-09-15"}';
    $json_string = str_replace("\\n", "", $json_string);
    var_dump(json_encode($json_string));
    //ShowDebug("Test1:" . $json_string);
    //$json_string = '{"foo-bar": 12345}'
    $json = json_decode($json_string ,true);
    var_dump(json_decode($json_string ,true));
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            ShowDebug(' - No errors');
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            ShowDebug(' - Maximum stack depth exceeded');
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            ShowDebug(' - Underflow or the modes mismatch');
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            ShowDebug(' - Unexpected control character found');
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            ShowDebug(' - Syntax error, malformed JSON');
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            ShowDebug(' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded');
        break;
        default:
        ShowDebug(' - Unknown error');
        break;
    }
    foreach ($json as $value)
    {
        ShowDebug("Testing: $value->tomorrow");
        
    }
```

Here is my test JSON file:

```json
[
    {
        "Test": "hello",
        "Test2": "Hi"
    },
    {
        "Test": "Goodbye",
        "Test2": "Bye"
    }
]
```

Here is a var dump of the encode and decode, when using the JSON inside the php file:

```
string(31) ""{\"tomorrow\":\"2018-09-15\"}""   <---- This is the var dump of encode
array(1) {
  ["tomorrow"]=>                               <--- This is the var dump of decode
  string(10) "2018-09-15"
}
```

Here is another var dump of the encode and decode when using the JSON from another file:

```
string(202) ""[\r\n    {\r\n        \\\"Test\\\": \\\"hello\\\",\r\n        \\\"Test2\\\": \\\"Hi\\\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n        \\\"Test\\\": \\\"Goodbye\\\",\r\n        \\\"Test2\\\": \\\"Bye\\\"\r\n    }\r\n]""   <--- This is encode
NULL       <--- This is decode
```

EDIT: updated based on comments

I removed the encode from the var dump, and removed the string replace, and new output is:

```
string(150) "[
    {
        \"Test\": \"hello\",
        \"Test2\": \"Hi\"
    },
    {
        \"Test\": \"Goodbye\",
        \"Test2\": \"Bye\"
    }
]"
NULL
```

Comment: So what does `json_last_error()` tell you?

Comment: `var_dump(json_encode($json_string));` makes no sense BTW because the data is already JSON. Just `var_dump($json_string);` would be better for debugging

Comment: @ADyson it says "Syntax error, malformed JSON"

Comment: What happens if you remove `$json_string = str_replace("\\n", "", $json_string);`? That shouldn't really be necessary I don't think?

Comment: If you're about to put code / data into the comments...please don't. It belongs in your question. Use the "edit" button of your question to post an update there. Thanks :-)

Comment: @ADyson I have updated sorry about that this is my first question on Stack lol

Comment: Anyway it looks like your JSON is already double-encoded somehow, based on that output. Those `\ ` (backslashes) shouldn't be there before the quote marks. If your JSON file is actually exactly as you've shown in the question then it wouldn't have this problem - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f478aa80a3c82935e6574ce9cedc0f4daf925649 . But it seems that somehow it isn't. You should double-check.

Comment: No problem to be new, we all start somewhere. But please, I strongly advise you to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - I can see from your profile that you didn't, although I believe it's recommended to all new users. Then you have a better idea overall of how the site works. It only takes a few minutes to read.

Comment: @ADyson everything is exactly as show and was just copied and pasted from the file on the server from my IDE. That is exactly what is confusing to me about this from everything I have read it should just work.

Comment: "everything is exactly as show"...but it can't be. Otherwise you wouldn't have a problem, as far as I can see. Like I said, please just double-check.

Comment: If we start with the string as shown in your var_dump then it produces exactly the error you're reporting - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c34cd9cc9e41702708f57e2a18e42eb8f448779

Comment: @ADyson Doing a double check on the file. It shows nothing out of the ordinary and looks the same and I show above. For my double check I moved my editor (vscode) out of json language select to plain text to check for any thing then also logged on to the server via putty and vi'ed the file and all looks the same. If there is another way I should do a double check please let me know.

Comment: I just copied your code and data into a php and json file (respectively) on my local PHP server and ran it, so it's actually loading from a real file, not a string. It loads fine, doesn't have the problem you report. I can only assume you've maybe missed something. Maybe you're not loading the file you think you are, or not running the code you think you are, or something like that. I can't really help you any more - the information you've provided doesn't reproduce the problem you're seeing.